# One large controller vs many smaller controllers for performance

Tags: performance, optimization, controller, structure, sencha-touch-2.2

I am building an app that has about 40 screen in it amongst 4 tabs. I am trying to figure out what is the best way to structure the controllers. 40 views and matching 40 controllers? Or does it make sense to have 4 controllers and then all the logic for views under that tab to be consolidated in each controller?

Which is better from a performance perspective?

How does Sencha Touch map controllers to views? Is there a convention to follow that will automate this (similar to EmberJS or other Javascript frameworks)? Or, do I have to always use the refs property of the controller config object to define which objects I want to listen for/work with?